# Compile Jython3 sources on Windows

Tags: java, python, git, jython

CONTEXT :

1. I need to call a "file.py", where is implement my class "myClass", by the Python language OR the JAVA language through Jython.

I do in my "file.py" :

```
try :
    # Jython source file
    from com.local.mylocal.jython import ImyClass
except :
    ImyClass = None

from threading          import Thread

class myClassMetaClass(type) :
    def __new__() :
        if IClient is None :
            bases = (Thread,)
        else : 
            bases = (Thread, ImyClass,)
    return type.__new__(metacls, nom, bases, dict)

class myClass(metaclass=myClassMetaClass) :
    pass
```

2. When I run my PYTHON code, my class : myClass is instance with all metaclass she need. My code run.
3. When I run my JAVA code who call my PY class through Jython, my code error is :

> Exception in thread "main" SyntaxError: ("mismatched input '='
>   expecting RPAREN", ('../file.py', 52, 22, 'class
>   myClass(metaclass=myClassMetaClass) :\n')) Blockquote

INVESTIGATION :

1. I see in "https://github.com/jython/jython3" ***isaiah*** solved my probleme.

PROBLEME :

1. I can't compile the source code on my Windows environement (need : POSIX ...).
2. I need the "jython3.jar" file.

REQUEST :

1. How compile jython3 souces on my Windows environement ?
2. Is it possible to acces to a "jython3.jar" file ?